# Shopify theme edit to change bundles copy

Tags: shopify

I'm really sorry if this is the wrong place but I'm a beginner and I've been trying to find this answer for a long time and can't.

I use Shopify and also the Shopify bundles app, for bundling products.

When the items within the bundle have variants, the name of the item and then the name of the variant option is displayed in the store front.

[For example in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdMpJ.png) the items in the bundle are are "test item 1" and "test item 2" and the variant options for both are "size".  I want this just just display as "Size" without showing the name of the item. In other words I just want the variant option name to show and not the product name.

I did speak with Shopify who referred me to their community but I didn't get an answer, the post is here:

https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apps/change-variant-copy-when-using-shopify-bundles-app/td-p/2499063

I don't even know where to start so if anyone knows or has any ideas I'd love to hear. thank you :)

Comment: Unless your question is regarding programming it's unlikely that you will get any help here I'm afraid. I suggest you revert back to your vendor's support system for help.